# How to write this python code. I have tried it but didn't work

Tags: python, pandas

```
from seaborn import load_dataset

df = load_dataset("diamonds")

df.head()
```

for example, I want to Create a list diamonds, in which each element is a dictionary with the keys being carat, cut, colour, clarity, depth, table, and price and the values being their corresponding values in df_new. The first element in diamonds looks as below Thanks

```
{'carat': 0.23,

'cut': 'Ideal',

'color': 'E',

'clarity': 'SI2',

'depth': 61.5,

'table': 55.0,

'price': 326}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a list of dicts with the specific fields, use

```py
df[['carat', 'cut', 'color', 'clarity', 'depth', 'table', 'price']].to_dict('records')
```

Here's the 1st entry:

```
{'carat': 0.23,
 'cut': 'Ideal',
 'color': 'E',
 'clarity': 'SI2',
 'depth': 61.5,
 'table': 55.0,
 'price': 326}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your dictionary / list:

```
diamonds = {
"carat": 0.23,
"cut": "Ideal",
"color": "E"
}
```

Verify it's correct:

```
print(diamonds)
```